# PHP insert into two different table

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I need to know if I can insert some data, into two database tables..

I have the following code, wich verify if user is logged on:

```
<?php
// Start the session (pretty important!)
session_start();

// Establish a link to the database
$dbLink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'DBUSER', 'PW');
if (!$dbLink) die('Can\'t establish a connection to the database: ' . mysql_error());

$dbSelected = mysql_select_db('DBNAME', $dbLink);
if (!$dbSelected) die ('We\'re connected, but can\'t use the table: ' . mysql_error());

$isUserLoggedIn = false;  
$query      = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE session_id = "' . session_id() . '" LIMIT 1';  
$userResult     = mysql_query($query);  
if(mysql_num_rows($userResult) == 1){  
$_SESSION['user'] = mysql_fetch_assoc($userResult);  
$isUserLoggedIn = true;  
}else{  
if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) != 'index.php'){  
    header('Location: index.php');  
    exit;  
}  
}  
?>
```

Database look's like:

Database table : **users**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| id | name | email | password | registered_date | session_id |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

The HTML form is not necessary, because you know how it looks.

Now I have the following code, which insert some data to database table. Its different database table from upper code.

That its the php code:

```
<?php
include ('adresa-site.php');
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'DBUSER';
$dbpass = 'PW';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
die('Eroare de conexiune: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
{
$link = $web_site.''.$_POST["stire"].'?idstire='.$_POST["idstire"];
$poza = addslashes ($_POST['poza']);
$nume = addslashes ($_POST['nume']);
$prenume = addslashes ($_POST['prenume']);
$varsta = addslashes ($_POST['varsta']);
$localitatea = addslashes ($_POST['localitatea']);
$numep = addslashes ($_POST['numep']);
$idstire = addslashes ($_POST['idstire']);
$stire = addslashes ($_POST['stire']);
$data = gmDate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
else
{
$link = $web_site."".$_POST['stire']."?idstire=".$_POST['idstire'];
$poza = htmlentities($_POST['poza'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5);
$nume = htmlentities($_POST['nume'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5);
$prenume = htmlentities($_POST['prenume'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5);
$varsta = $_POST["varsta"];
$localitatea = htmlentities($_POST['localitatea'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5);
$numep = htmlentities($_POST['numep'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5);
$idstire = htmlentities($_POST['idstire'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5);
$stire = $_POST["stire"];
$data = gmDate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO stiri2".
   "(link, poza, nume, prenume, varsta, localitatea, numep, idstire, stire, accesari,         data) ".
               "VALUES('$link','$poza','$nume','$prenume','$varsta','$localitatea','$numep','$idstire','$stire','$accesari', NOW())";
mysql_select_db('DBNAME');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
die('Nu s-au putut adauga datele: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "

<p class='text-center'>Copiaza si trimite link-ul de mai jos, prietenului tau</p>

<textarea rows='2' cols='55'>http://site.ro/" . $_POST['stire'] . "?idstire="     . $_POST['idstire'] . "</textarea>

<br />
<p class='text-center'>Acceseaza <a target='_blank'href='http://site.ro/" .     $_POST['stire'] . "?idstire=" . $_POST['idstire'] . "'>ACEST</a> link pentru     previzualizare</p>

";
mysql_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Database looks like:

Database table : **stiri2**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | link | poza | nume | prenume | varsta | localitatea | numep | idstire | stire | data | accesari |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now user from **users** database table, want to insert new information into **stiri2** database table.

I must get **session_id** from **users** database table, and update **users** and **stiri2** database tables with inserted information.

I will create a little map:

User it's logged in, and his **session_id** is for example, **328234917238914**.

Now he want to insert some new information, which will be stored in **stiri2** database table.

Every user will add their information, so I must do something to not overlap the inserted information.

What I need to know, it's how to make insert for current user..

Comment: Why do you need to save the `session_id` in the database ? You can corelate the info with the user id.

Comment: it's not necesay session_id , but i need to know how to make insert for every user !

Comment: nobody can help me with that problem? It's so complicated? :( .. for me is, but i think not for you guys !

Comment: It's not complicated, but you need to read stackoverflow help pages and http://whathaveyoutried.com. After that, try and solve the issue yourself. After that, post a question that is more concise and generalist. Well, if you do that, you probably will find your answers before posting the question

Comment: Ok .. i will try to solve myself. i've hope if someone can help me, cuz im newbie on php.

Answer (score 1):

What are you looking for is probably something like this: mysql_insert_id http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-insert-id.php

What you do is the following: A user registrates, you get that id and us this as your userID.

You can store this userid in the session.

If your user logs in, you will look up this id and use it in your other queries.

Comment: Ty for your comment. i will read entire page from php.net . Plus 1

Comment: i've found something interesting .. <strong>Insert into stiri2 (Select * from users where id='CURENT ID')</strong>  ..It is the corect one?

Comment: @MuzicaVeche you should retrieve your UserID while checking the credentials of your user

Comment: i've try that: `$sql = "INSERT INTO stiri".
       "(link, poza, nume, prenume, varsta, localitatea, idstire, stire, accesari, data) ".
       "VALUES('$link','$poza','$nume','$prenume','$varsta','$localitatea','$idstire','$stire','$accesari', NOW())".
       "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$_SESSION['id']."' LIMIT 1 ";` , but not working.. Have you another solution?